# When is it possible to set each term in a matrix equation equal to the zero vector simultaneously?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $A,B,C \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ be fixed and let $x,y,z \in M_{3 \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ be any three column vectors. Consider the matrix equation given by

$Ax + By + Cz = 0_{3 \times 1}$

All multiplication of matrices is the usual row-column definition. I am interested in when the following three relations simultaneously hold:

$Ax = 0_{3 \times 1}$

$By = 0_{3 \times 1}$

$Cz = 0_{3 \times 1}$

That is, what property or properties must $A$,$B$, and $C$ possess in order to make this so? I thought about this for a while, but haven't really come to a very good conclusion yet. Any ideas?

Comment: One case where this works is when the ranges of $A,B,C$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Why should that be the case?

Comment: If the sum of three orthogonal vectors $u,v,w$ is $0$ then, taking inner product with $u$ we get $\|u\|^{2}=0$ so $u=0$. Similarly, $v=w=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.